# Non Negative ODE Solutions with functools in R?

Tags: python, r, matlab, ode, functools

I am trying to implement an R algortihm dealing with non-negative ODE Systems. I need something like ode45 in MATLAB to define states which have to be none-negative.

I discussed about that already 3 years ago but with no real solution. deSolve is still not the way to go. I found some python code which looks very promising. Maybe this is possible in R as well. In the end I have to define a function wraper, as functools in python. What it does is pretty simple. Here is the code the of the python wraper:

```py
def wrap(f):

        @wraps(f)

        def wrapper(t, y, *args, **kwargs):

            low = y < 0

            y = np.maximum(y, np.ones(np.shape(y))*0)

            result = f(t, y, *args, **kwargs)

            result[too_low]  = np.maximum(result[low], np.ones(low.sum())*0)


            return result

        return wrapper

    return wrap
```

I mean in python this is straight forward. The wraper will be used in each step of the integration called by

```
solver = scipy.integrate.odeint(f, y0)
solution = solver.solve()
```

Is the same possible in R? I know there is a functools package and functools function, as well. But I have no clue if this really works. Can I use events in deSolve for that?

I am working now on this project for 5 years and I am out of ideas. I used an MATLAB, C++ and Python interface but all this is to slow, I need it in R. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm not seeing a [MCVE]. If this "was discussed" then you should provide a link. Providing code in python using one of its external packages isn't going to be particularly informative to R programmers. Similarly uninformative is saying deSolve "doesn't work".

Comment: Are you solving for a steady state solution? `stode` and `steady.1D` from `deSolve` have `positive =  TRUE` for ensuring solutions are positive. Also, `ode45` is implemented as a method in `deSolve`. It would be helpful if you gave us an R example that doesn't give your desired result, so that we can fix it to give your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

deSolve does not support automatic non-negativity constraints for good reasons. We had such questions several times in the past, but it turned out in all these cases, that the reason of the negative value was an incomplete model specification. The typical case is that something is exported from an empty pool. Because unwanted negative values are usually an indicator of an inadequate model specification, we do (currently) not consider to add a "non-negative" constraint in the future.

Example: in the following equation, X can become negative by model design:

dX/dt = -k

whereas the following cannot:

dX/dt = -k * X

If you need a linear decrease "most of the time" that reduces to zero shortly before X becomes zero, you can use a Monod-type safeguard (or something similar):

dX/dt = -k*X / (k2 + X)

The selection of k2 is relatively uncritical. It should be small enough not to influence the overall behavior and not too small, compared to the numerical accuracy of the solver.

Another method to avoid negative values is to work in log-transformed space. Here are some related threads:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2010q2/000028.html

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2013q3/000222.html

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2016/000437.html

In addition, it is of course also possible to write an own wrapper in R.

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you for your answer. I really need some kind of wrapper in this context. Do you have any idea how to implement that? Or is it just posible to call an event function at each timestep of deSolve?

Comment: If and how a wrapper is needed, depends on the particular problem. Can you please add a minimum reproducible example, i.e. a small model in R where you think that negative values are a problem?